# What is correct use of definite article "the"?

Tags: grammar

They hiked the price and demand wasn't decreasing.

Or

They hiked the price and, the demand wasn't decreasing.

Comment: Neither. "They hiked the price, and the demand didn't decrease."

Comment: Thank you, Mac can you write the above comment by using one "the"?

Comment: You could, as, "They hiked the price, and demand didn't increase." It doesn't change the meaning to omit the article on "demand".

Comment: Thank you, Mac. Loads of love from India.